# Не совсем понимаю как решить подобную задачу

Tags: c#, массивы, комбинаторика

Можете подсказать — как решить такую задачу? В каком направлении думать?
Тз задачи.

п.1 имеется список слов 300 штук
п.2 имеется 8 ячеек для слов, далее - комплект.
п.3 В комплекте могут быть только уникальные слова из списка, без повторений.
п.4 порядок слов имеет значение - один и тот же набор из 8 слов, но с расположением в разных ячейках дает другой комплект
пример -

Яблоко, джинсы, крем, мыло, телефон, бутылка, лампа, сумка - это один комплект.
Сумка, яблоко, джинсы, крем, мыло, телефон, бутылка, лампа, - это уже другой комплект.

Имея 2 переменных (п.1 и п.2 ) необходимо написать формулу подсчета количество комплектов с учетом правила п.3 и п.4.
с пояснениями.

Comment: Например, [комбинаторика](https://fmclass.ru/math.php?id=4986cacac0f94)

Comment: Да, все верно, можно поменять слово местами, чтобы получить новый комплект

Comment: а если без комбинаторики?

Comment: Да, верно - главное, чтобы не было одинаковых комплектов

Comment: Формула-то простая, число вариантов (размещений) немалое `300! / 292!`

Comment: "!" - это факториал? не припомню что это значит

Comment: Да, факториал...

Comment: не совсем понял - откуда 292 получилось?

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать — как можно посчитать количество уникальных значений с помощью формулы

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно, сделал рабочий вариант подсчета уникальных значений в списке и всего сколько тоже считает.

```
private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files";
        string pattern = @"\b(ArtId=[0-9]*)\b";

        int count = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files\Words.txt").Length;

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files\target.txt"))
        {
            List<string> linesToWrite = new List<string>();
            List<string> linesToWrite2 = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files\Words.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    string line;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        string newString = sr.ReadLine();
                        linesToWrite.Add(newString);
                    }
                }
            }

            linesToWrite2 = linesToWrite.Distinct().ToList();

            Variables.Variables.unicResults = linesToWrite2.Count.ToString();

            // Выводим количество вариантов - уникальных и всего
            resultBox.Text += Variables.Variables.unicResults;
            totalOptions.Text += count.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("Работа выполнена");
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где тут подсчет количества комплектов? Это получается ответ  вовсе не на заданный вопрос, а "как мне прочитать из файла"

Comment: тут пока нет, только чтение из файла. Комплекты делаю

Comment: комплекты более или менее сделал... надо подправить

Answer (score 0):

Более или менее разобрался с подсчетом комплектов.
Что получилось:

```
private void CountOfVariants(int n)
    {
        int N = 0;
        int[,] a = new int[Variables.Variables.countOfNums, Variables.Variables.countOfWords]; // Размерность массива, по ТЗ 300 и 8

        int x = n % 7;
        int y = n / 7;
        for (int k, j, i = 1; i <= 7 && N < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
                if (a[y, j] == i) break;
            if (j < x) continue;
            for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
                if (a[j, x] == i) break;
            if (j < y) continue;
            if (y > 0 && x > 0)
            {
                int b = a[y, x - 1];
                for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < 6; k++)
                        if (a[j, k] == b && a[j, k + 1] == i) break;
                    if (k < 6) break;
                }
                if (j < y) continue;
            }
            a[y, x] = i;
            if (n < 34) CountOfVariants(n + 1);
            else
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                        Console.Write(" " + a[j, k]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                N++;
            }
        }
    }
```

но! при построении, у меня матрица получается такого вида:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7
```

вместо 7 может быть 1 или 2, или 3, или 4, или 5, а должна матрица вся заполняться цифрами, те каждый ряд должны быть уникальным. Вроде так правильно.
Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Answer (score -1):

Пошел таким путем:

```
private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files";
        string pattern = @"\b(ArtId=[0-9]*)\b";

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Files\Words.txt"))
        {
            var lineToWrite = new SortedDictionary<string,string>();

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                lineToWrite.Clear();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    string line;
                    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string newString = line.Substring(0, 8);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        if (match.Success && !lineToWrite.ContainsKey(newString))
                        {
                            lineToWrite.Add(newString, file + " " + newString + " " + match.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach(var kvp in lineToWrite)
                {
                    sw.Write(kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Работа выполнена");
        }
    }
```

но вылетает ошибка, что файл Words уже используется другим процессом. Что не так делаю?

Comment: если точно что пишет: The process cannot access the file Words.txt, because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: `File.CreateText` - файл создан и хендл на него удерживается в `sw`. Далее в цикле `foreach` попадается этот же файл.

Comment: Спасибо, Это исправил. Где substring (0,8) получил другую ошибку: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Comment: Вопрос с выполнением кода решил, код работает, но почему-то не пишется ничего в файл target.txt